# Select all column values as total and multiply it

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my DB structure:

**Invoice**

- ID
- Company

**InvoiceLine**

- LineID
- Quantity
- Price

These are my rows:

```
Invoice
ID  Company
1   XYZ
2   ZYX

InvoiceLine
LineID  InvoiceID   quantity    price
1       1           1           10
2       1           5           10

3       2           1           20
```

What I'm trying to generate is to select my total invoice price dynamically:

**IDEAL RESULT**

```
1 XYZ 60
2 ZYX 20
```

I use the following query for this:

```
select ID, cil.quantity * cil.unitPrice as invoiceTotal from Invoice ci
join InvoiceLine as cil on ci.invoiceID = cil.invoiceID
```

Problem is that this query returns 2 rows for the first invoice.

Why is this and what how could I select ALL values of my invoice lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `group by`:

```
select ci.id, sum(cil.quantity * cil.unitPrice) as invoiceTotal
from Invoice ci join
     InvoiceLine cil
     on ci.invoiceID = cil.invoiceID 
group by ci.id;
```

However, you don't even need the `join`:

```
select cil.id, sum(cil.quantity * cil.unitPrice) as invoiceTotal
from InvoiceLine cil
group by cil.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    select Invoice.id,Invoice.Company sum(InvoiceLine.quantity * InvoiceLine.unitPrice) as TotalSum
    from Invoice join
         InvoiceLine cil
         on Invoice.invoiceID = InvoiceLine.invoiceID 
    group by Invoice.id,Invoice.Company

order by Invoice.Company ;
```